# add an attribute in a model class after deploy a appcelerator titanium app

Tags: model, attributes, titanium, appcelerator

i write a app with appcelerator titanium and want to add an attribute in a model class. I must write a migration to prevent android errors with "..has no column.."

(http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations-section-36739597_AlloySyncAdaptersandMigrations-Migrations)

I just want to drop the table "favorites":

```
migration.up = function(migrator) {
    migrator.dropTable("favorites");
};
```

Why it doesn't work and the error message is still where?

`migrator.createTable(...)` also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

create a migration file:
   alloy generate migration favorites

add the following code:
  migration.up = function(migrator) {

```
migrator.dropTable("favorites");

migrator.createTable({
    columns: {
        "id": 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT',

        "title":"text",
        "url":"text",
        "some_new_column":"text"

     }
 });
```

};

migration.down = function(migrator) {
    migrator.dropTable("favorites");

};